# Is it possible to apply a configuration transformation for an AppHarbor test project?

Tags: .net, appharbor

It's stated in the AppHarbor documentation that configuration transformations are applied for both website and background worker config files. However, I have a non-executable, non-deployable integration test project that requires an app.config transform for the Test environment.

So far I've not had any success with this the following file structure, and I'm guessing that AppHarbor doesn't support configuration transformation on DLL projects during the Test execution build step:

```
Specs.proj
+
+-- Specs.dll.config
    +
    +-- Specs.dll.Debug.config
    +
    +-- Specs.dll.Test.config
```

Does anybody know if this should be possible?

Comment: Have you checked the docs? http://support.appharbor.com/kb/getting-started/managing-environments

Comment: @jrummell I have, yes. The docs only refer to transformations for the Release environment and mention web and background worker (.exe) projects, but not .dll projects.

Comment: Right, transforming dll config doesn't make sense. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Transforming config for library projects (dlls) just doesn't make sense. Your application will use the app.config of your exe or web.config of your web application.

So you'll need to copy the relevant config settings from your dll config to your exe/web config transformations.

**Update**

Since this is for running tests, I'd recommend a different approach: injecting them as dependencies. See [Configuration Settings Are A Dependency That Should Be Injected](http://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/configuration-settings-are-a-dependency-that-should-be-injected) for an excellent post on this topic.

Here's an opinionated excerpt that changed my thinking:

> So why is it a hack to add config settings to your unit test project?
>   Well, web.config and app.config are files just like any other. So
>   referencing configuration settings within a class means that that
>   class has a direct dependency on the filesystem. You wouldn't feel so
>   comfortable (i hope) if your unit test opened up a file in My
>   Documents, or downloaded a web page from the Internet, so why do
>   people think that is is acceptable to access web.config?

Comment: I'm not running a web project or background worker application during the test build phase; The AppHarbor build system is running tests (using a test runner), which uses the config files found in the the test project (which is a DLL). Or at least, that's how it works locally, both from the MsBuild CLI and under Visual Studio.

Comment: Now I understand. I tried going down that road with a CI server, I ended up injecting my settings with a DI framework.

Comment: Also note that we're currently only applying release transformations before deploying, not test transformations.

Comment: @jrummell Your DI revision makes an excellent point, so I've voted up for that, but the answer to the original question was given by friism in his comment. I will alter my code to take this answer into account, but also consider the DI approach that you've suggested. Thanks.

Comment: @jrummell I've thought some more, and I've decided that perhaps I was asking the wrong question! As such, your answer is a good one and it's what I ended up doing anyway; I'm now injecting my configuration dependencies. This will also help others with the same question. Marked as 'answered' – Thanks.

Comment: I can think of a good counter-argument to this: I don't want to reveal my database connection strings usernames, or test username/passwords  on an open source project that appharbor builds. These are selenium web tests that use remote drivers, so appharbor not transforming the app.config is a bit of a pain in the ass

Comment: @ChrisS. I agree. My project on AppHarbor doesn't use a database so it wasn't a concern for me. For other open source projects I host with WinHost, and keep my sensitive config files in a private BitBucket repository that gets uploaded as part of my automated deployment process.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to use the app harbor config values for integration testing. I wasn't able to get it to work having app harbor inject the correct config settings, but I got close.

I added an app.config to my web project because my web project has my integration tests in it.

I added the environment app setting to app.config:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="Environment" value="localconfig"/>
```

I noticed when that code ran on app harbor the environment value was **Test:27017**.

I wrote this code:

```
private static string GetMongoDbConnectionString()
{
    string con = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("MONGOHQ_URL") ??
                ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("MONGOLAB_URI");
    string env = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("Environment");
    if (env.StartsWith("Test", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    {
        con = "mongodb://xxxxxxxxx";
    }
    return con;
}
```

Where the xxxxxxxxx is the value I want to use at integration test time.